# Unite.vim file_rec/async command is not executable

Tags: vim, vundle, unite.vim

I'm using gVim with Vundle on Windows XP and 7. I have Unite.vim installed and I am trying to use the file_rec/async command to search for files. I've installed Vimproc.vim by executing the following commands:

```
cd .vim\bundle\vimproc.vim
make -f make_mingw32.mak
```

When I open gVim and enter the following in command mode:

```
:Unite file_rec/async
```

I get the following error:

```
[file_rec/async] async command : "" is not executable.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm author of unite.vim.

In Windows, you should not use file_rec/async source. It is too slow and
not easy to use. You should use file_rec source instead.

Comment: Wow. Nice to meet you. I'm a fan of your work. Thanks for answering.